# Get Some Attributes with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I was having some practices with programming, and I got stuck (also because of my lacking knowledge of web programming) in this part: I was to get some information from this page: http://db.fowtcg.us/index.php?p=card&code=VS01-003+R , but only the card properties, and I'm struggling a little with JSoup, I was able to fetch the data with:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://db.fowtcg.us/?p=card&code=TTW-080+SR").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("div.card-props");
        System.out.println(newsHeadlines);
```

But I couldn't get the data back from the Element object (but i could see it was there debugging).

How can i proceed in order to fetch this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use this instead:

```
Elements property = doc.select("div.col-xs-12.col-sm-7.box.card-props");
```

You need to make sure the `selector` you use match the original `html` document exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much! It did work.
I used other expression to match:
`div.col-xs-3.col-sm-3.prop-label`, was more specific, but yours cleared it out for me!

Now I'm trying to figure it out how to make the information out of the html tag, example:

`from <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 prop-label">
 Cost
</div>`

get only  "Cost"

Comment: BTW, using the method `ownText()`, i was able to get only the information i wanted! Just need to check for when isn't a text, but thanks a lot!

Comment: You could also get text by `text()`, which will return you ALL texts under that  element, whereas `ownText()` gives you ONLY the text that element has :) Glad to be of help! Please kindly consider accept it as answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: I was checking on debug, and usually was being created one array of elements, but only the first element had something (going deep enough, it was even able to find the text i was looking for).

But in case when the element has a class itself like
`<span class='mark_abilities'>Awakening</span>` or it's a link to another thing, how can i fetch? Because on the Array of elements, it comes as Null.

Comment: I coulnd't edit my last comment u.u , unfortunally I'm at work and i can't test the code yet, but i think `[attr*=value]` can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains/ends-with selector also

```
//contains
Elements property = doc.select("div[class*=card-props]");

//ends-with
Elements property = doc.select("div[class$=card-props]");
```

Go through below link to know more about css selectors.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax